# Spray Path Matching the Rest of String

Tags: spray

I've been using Spray for a while and I'm trying to match a URI that looks like this:

```
http GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/sec/company/file/txt/2012QTR1/0000018255-12-000005_finalDoc.html
```

The DSL that I wrote is like this:

```
pathPrefix("sec") {
  //...some other routes
  pathPrefix("company") {
     pathPrefix("file") {
        path("txt" / Segment) { fileName =>
          get {
            complete(fileName)
          }
        } ~
        path("html" / Segment) { fileName =>
          get {
            complete(fileName)
          }
        } ~ complete(NotFound)
  } 
}
```

I'm trying to match `2012QTR1/0000018255-12-000005_finalDoc.html` which can be then converted into an actual path to the requested file.

I noticed the `("txt" / Segment)` can only match a URI with one segment, not the whole string, but how can I match the rest of the text without having to write something like `("txt" / Segment / Segment / Segment)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Rest or RestPath instead.  From the [docs](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-routing/path-directives/pathmatcher-dsl/):

> `Rest: PathMatcher1[String]` Matches and extracts the complete remaining
>   unmatched part of the request’s URI path as an (encoded!) String. If
>   you need access to the remaining decoded elements of the path use
>   RestPath instead.
>
> `RestPath: PathMatcher1[Path]` Matches and extracts
>   the complete remaining, unmatched part of the request’s URI path.

Comment: I think it means URL encoding like space is encoded as %20 and / is %2F.

Comment: Well, if I use `RestPath`, it actually causes error, so I had to stick with `Rest`.